# Create a JSON request with user input

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, jsonp

I want to make a JSON request to the TMDB database using a user search input. A search request would look like this http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query=Bond&callback=angular.callbacks._0 This is the search request for "Bond".

I have a search function,

```
$scope.search = function() {

  var base = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3';
  var service = '/search/movie';
  var apiKey = 'a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query='
  var search = searchquery
  var callback = 'JSON_CALLBACK'; // provided by angular.js
  var url = base + service + '?api_key=' + apiKey + search + '&callback=' + callback;

  $http.jsonp(url).
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

      if (status == 200) {
        $scope.movieList = data.results;
        console.log($scope.movieList)
      } else {
        console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
      }

    }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
    });
}

var searchquery = "Bond"
```

As you can see I have a variable called `searchquery` at the moment I give this a value, but I want to fill this with user input.

And this is my view.

```
%h1
  Logo
%li
  = link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete)

%div{"ng-app" => "app.exampleApp"}
  %div{"ng-controller" => "exampleCtrl"}

    %input{"ng-change" => "search(searchquery)", "ng-model" => "searchquery", "ng-model-options" => "{ debounce: 2000 }"}
    %span
      {{ searchquery }}

    %div{"ng-repeat" => "movie in movieList"}
      {{ movie.original_title }}
```

Currently this shows all the titles from the JSON data.

How do I use the user value from the input to do the apropiate search request?

Answer (score 0):

Since you binded `searchquery` to the `ng-model` of your input. You can access this value in your controller with `$scope.searchquery`

You also should consider using `params` object to give the URL query params :

```
var apiKey = 'a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4';
var url = base + service;

$http.jsonp(url,{
  params: {
    "api_key" : apiKey,
    "search" : $scope.searchquery,
    "callback" : callback,
  }
}).success()
```

This should go the trick and is a lot easier to understand (instead of building yourself the URL)

Hope it helped